# ExoPlayer - get total duration with ConcatenatingMediaSource

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to put together a seamless player using the `ExoPlayer` and `ConcatenatingMediaSource`. The general idea is:

1. I have a set of X short tracks (~15s each), kept in *Assets*
2. I load each of them into a `ExtractorMediaSource`
3. I put all of them into one `ConcatenatingMediaSource`

The solution works perfectly, but there is one flaw - `ConcatenatingMediaSource` seems to be loading media sources dynamically, not all at once.

This created a problem, because iterating `Period` objects from the `Timeline` to accumulate the total duration does not work. It will add up to X, but when the playback reaches a certain point, it will jump to X+15.

Any tips on how to get the total duration in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

i met the same problem before and here comes my solution:

extend a `LoadControl`

override a `shouldContinueLoading` returning true to make sure the `ExoPlayerImplInternal` keeps updating periods,so that the playlist would loaded at once.

i hope it helps